# BitLocker with Auto-Unlock / SQL Server Services manually

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, bitlocker

I have a Window Server 2012 R2 Server (vmware) with a SQL Server Database running on it.  For security purposes we installed BitLocker on it. The objective was to encrypt our “data at rest”.   The only problem so far is that each time we restart the server we have to manually start the SQL Server services. We already implemented the auto unlock feature of BitLocker. Any idea on what could be happening?

Comment: Try changing the SQL Server services to delayed Automatic startup to give BitLocker enough time to unlock the drive. If that doesn't work you can increase the startup delay of the SQL Server services via the registry.